# How to create toggle buttons generated by for loops in angular 4/6

Tags: angular, typescript, button

I have created this demo, in which I have three buttons. These are generated through for loop running on backend response.

all the buttons are clickable and turning activate and deactivate with click event but what logic should I have to use to make only one button active at a time. (it should work like toggle button but these are not the toggle buttons)

so the selection of anyone button will make other 2 deactivate.

Please see the demo code on like below,

[updated code / current working logic](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3qv8ow?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: you could use the radio-button for grouping the buttons, then only 1 will be enabled. or you could have something like a 'disabled' property. When clicking on a button, you can simply loop through the array and disable all the other buttons

Comment: These are not the radio buttons, I have a requirement of multiple individual buttons, It contains a lot more information than just name.
This is just an example of buttons

Comment: You can make a radio button look like anything you want, including buttons, and still use the group functionality. Personally I'd op for that as opposed to introducing new logic/more code to do loops etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified the code, make it like this

```
  someMethod(something) {
    this.groupOfButton.forEach(btn => {
       btn['active'] = (btn.number === something.number);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @VivekKumar for the logic, It works so smooth, I was not able to figure out the equation part but thanks to you now I know.
My only other question is, can I make toggle? 
Like if the same button clicked again it should get deactivated. I tried to do it with your logic but it is not toggling the button

Comment: @jay, i updated the answer to toggle (you will see it when it gets accepted). You just need an if statement `if (btn.number === something.number) {
         btn['active'] = !btn['active'];
       }` inside the `forEach`

Comment: @yay, yes, you can! just play with the logic. The idea is to keep the data intact. Modify it when you want as you want.